# Adding functionality to my Entity Framework POCO classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've built a web application with Entity Framework using POCO.

I'm using these POCO classes as my business objects and not just for persisting data which works fine until...

Now I need to add some logic into these classes to do thing like total up sales, order lines, etc.

Should I add methods to my POCO classes to enable this functionality or leave them purely for persisting data and create some kind of 'processor' whereby I pass in the business objects and get the values I require out.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the architectural design you are using or want to use?

For example, if these are your domain entities, you should put as much as possible logic in them. If they are merely data containers and you don't have a real architecture in place, your logic would probably in some business component.

So if you provide your question with some more details, we can help you better.

Comment: Hi L-Three, At the moment I have an anaemic domain model whereby the POCO classes are just data containers and I have a service layer of methods. I'd like to move to a more OO design where the business objects provide their own logic. I just wasn't sure if this was possible when the objects are currently used for my Entity Framework  data persisting.

Comment: Your POCO's would become domain entities; mapped to the database by EF Code First. They contain data as well as domain logic; and you could add more DDD concepts like domain services etc. Then, your application layer would use your domain layer and contain application/business logic that is no part of your domain.

Comment: Add partial classes to your POCO objects